# Limiting vosk model vocabulary

Tags: python, speech-recognition, vosk

I am using the vosk-model-small-en-us-0.15 on a Raspberry Pi. Is there a way to limit the words it can transcribe? I know other models have a words list, but the one I am using does not seem to have one.

The model was downloaded from here:
https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models

Any help is appreciated :)